# Eclipse Luna with Nodeclipse hangs when navigating a .js file with the Outline view

Tags: javascript, eclipse, ide, nodeclipse

I'm running Eclipse Luna on an Ubuntu 14.04 system with EPIC Perl features and Nodeclipse installed. I can use the Outline view to move around an HTML file with no problem, but the IDE freezes completely when I do the same with a .js file. Has anyone else seen this behavior? I've tried removing components to narrow down the cause, and so far I've had no luck.

Comment: In short, try with the latest versions. Open issue/bug ticket